# Generating random number of loops

Tags: java, android, random

I have this problem that I have observed when generating numbers as a condition in a for loop.
I use this in my android program.

When I do this:

```
String temp = "";
for (int i = 0; i < new Random().nextInt(1000); i++) {
    temp += i + " ";
}
```

I always get no more than 100

But when I do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    temp += new Random().nextInt(1000) + " ";
}
```

I got real random numbers ranging from 0 to 999.

What is actually happening?

I know I could do this:

```
int x = new Random().nextInt(1000);
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    temp += i + " ";
}
```

And this does return random numbers from 0-999. But I just want to understand why the first code only returns numbers not more than 100.

Comment: Your first one loops until `i` is larger than a random number, and this random number is regenerated at each iteration. Your second one generates 10 random numbers. Your last one generates a sequence of numbers going from 0 to a a random number. They're all completely different, and you haven't specified what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first implementation ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < new Random().nextInt(1000); i++) {
    temp += i + " ";
}
```

is calling `new Random().nextInt(1000)` at the end of every iteration to determine if it's time to end the loop.  The same code could be rewritten as follows:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < new Random().nextInt(1000)) {
    temp += i + " ";
    i++;
}
```

which may be better illustrated as ...

```
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    if (i < new Random().nextInt(1000)) {
        break;
    }
    temp += i + " ";
    i++;
}
```

so although the value of `i` is constantly increasing, the number against which it is being compared `new Random().nextInt(1000)` is constantly changing.  Your comparisons might look like this ...

```
if (0 < 981) break;
if (1 < 27) break;
if (2 < 523) break;
if (3 < 225) break;
if (4 < 198) break;
if (5 < 4) break;
```

In the above example, even though the first call to `new Random().nextInt(1000)` is returning a whopping `981`, the loop only happens 5 times, because at the beginning of the 6th iteration, `new Random().nextInt(1000)` returned `4`, which is less than `5` the current value of `i`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for the clear explanation, although the randow is created at the **beginning** of each iteration.

Comment: I was thinking something like: 
the third part (increment) on the for loop statement will be the only one that would loop each time. I thought the second part (condition statement) would ran once and have the condition kind of constant just like the first part (initialization int i = 0) of the for loop. 
But I understood how the loop works now, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 0; i < new Random().nextInt(1000); i++) { // here upper limit of i will change time to time.
    temp += i + " ";
}
```

.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // here i increase up to   10
    temp += new Random().nextInt(1000) + " ";
}
```

.

```
int x = new Random().nextInt(1000); // here x is random but this will never change while for loop is running
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    temp += i + " ";
}
```

Comment: Oh! Okay thanks I got it!! I thought the third part (increment) on the for loop statement will be the only one that would loop each time. I thought the second part (condition statement) would ran once and have the condition kind of constant just like the first part (initialization int i = 0) of the for loop. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

In this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < new Random().nextInt(1000); i++) {
     temp += i + " ";
}
```

the variable i is incremented by one for each iteration of loop, but at a given point of time where i<100, there is a chance of a number smaller than 'i' get generated randomly and thus the loop exits.

Answer (score 2):

you should initialize random variable before cycle

```
int max =  new Random().nextInt(1000);
String temp = ""; 
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
 {      temp += i + " ";    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Java Doc says:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

So it is possible that value of i can be larger than the random generated by `nextInt()` and the loop exits.

As you are creating a new Random is generated using `nextInt(1000)` on each iteration of for loop, you will not get a fixed value for the loop and it will keep changing and so will your output.

```
String temp = "";
for (int i = 0; i < new Random().nextInt(1000); i++) { //new random nextInt() called on each iteration
    temp += i + " ";
}
```

Note: My program ran till `64`

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
String temp = "";
for (int i = 0; i < new Random().nextInt(1000); i++) {
        temp += i + " ";
    }
```

i may be bigger than 100 but probabilistically is practically impossible. yeah!

Comment: Actually I worked it out and it should occur 1 in 186 times. Probability is 999/1000* 998/1000*...*900/1000

Comment: 5.95e-6 = practically impossible :)

Answer (score 0):

The "first for loop" may give output numbers less than 100 but not always, **it will give a series of numbers from 0 to the random number which is returned by the Random.nextInt(1000) method**....

> 1st and 3rd looping methods works same...

but the **second one will pick 9 random numbers from 0 to 999 and the answer is like, (373 472 7 56 344 423 764 722 554 800)**